# auto filter in datagridview + searchtextbox

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, filtering, visual-studio-2019

i have an access database with an address table with different types of clients. a column with "type" and columns with data from that clients (adress, name , etc).

I have 3 buttons that open separate panels in the mainscreen that should show the 2 most relevant addresses, and 1 that shows all. In that screen i would like to filter trough the use of a textbox that will appear when they press the search button.

I'm trying to work with dragging the datagridview to my screen and now i need to know what code i should add to the textbox to make it filter the addresses in that datagridview.
My current code for that page is below here

```
Public Class Patienten


    Private Sub btnAddPatient_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnAddPatient.Click
        'maak hier een nieuwe klantenfiche in een nieuwe form (mainpatientform)
        'Dim Pat_frm As New MainPatientform
        'Pat_frm.display(MainPatientform.soortenum.nieuw)
        NewRelationForm.Show()
    End Sub

    Private Sub Tbl_RelatiesBindingNavigatorSaveItem_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
        Me.Validate()
        Me.Tbl_RelatiesBindingSource.EndEdit()
        Me.TableAdapterManager.UpdateAll(Me.PatientenDatabaseDataSetX)

    End Sub

    Private Sub Patienten_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        'TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'PatientenDatabaseDataSetX.tbl_Relaties' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
        Me.Tbl_RelatiesTableAdapter.Fill(Me.PatientenDatabaseDataSetX.tbl_Relaties)

    End Sub

    Private Sub Tbl_RelatiesDataGridView_CellContentClick(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles Tbl_RelatiesDataGridView.CellContentClick
        MainPatientform.Show()
        MainPatientform.TabControl1.SelectedIndex = 0


    End Sub

    Private Sub btnSearch_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnSearch.Click
        gbxSearhbox.Visible = True
    End Sub

    Private Sub txtSearchPatient_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles txtSearchPatient.TextChanged
        'no idea what to put in here
    End Sub
End Class
```

My other two screens don't have code yet (need this one first) but here i need an "autofilter" for a type of clients.
So when i open that list , i only get clients of type "x"
but since i can't even filter in the main screen, how to do that one too...
I'm a beginner

Comment: You set the `Filter` property of the `BindingSource` to filter the data that gets exposed.

Comment: @jmcilhinney : you answered ! thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks for the ideas.

The easiest answer was to simply add a line after i filled the grid:

```
 Private Sub Patienten_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        'TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'PatientenDatabaseDataSetX.tbl_Relaties' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
        Me.Tbl_RelatiesTableAdapter.Fill(Me.PatientenDatabaseDataSetX.tbl_Relaties)
        Me.Tbl_RelatiesBindingSource.Filter = "Rel_Type='Patient'" 'This line :-)
```

The filter bindingsource was the key!
Many thanks to @jmcilhinney for the comment!

Comment: Bear in mind that downloading a million rows of data out of a DB into a client, and then setting a client side filter to hide most of them is a huge waste.. Some combination of a Fill command that take a rel_type parameter and a bindingsource filter would probably be best..

Comment: There's a balance to be struck between filtering with a `WHERE` clause in your SQL and filtering locally with a `BindingSource`. If you have a small number of records and you will display them all at some point and some of them multiple times in different combinations then retrieving all the data first and filtering locally is more efficient. If you have a large number of records and will display only a small subset of them then filtering in SQL and querying multiple times is more efficient. For situations in between, you need to make a decision based on intuition and testing.

Comment: I am glad to hear that your problem has been solved, you can click '✔' to mark your reply as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

you have 2 options,

1. you filter your data in ms-access then throw it to your datatable,
2. you can filter your data programmatically by doing this :

'this is a c# example and there is an equivalent code in vb.

```
 var data = from x in myDataTable.asEnumerable()
 where x.Field<string>("type") == "typeofClient"
 select x;
```

after you filter programmatically, you can attach it to your datatable/dataadapter then display it to your datagridview.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to this document.
[DataTable.DefaultView Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datatable.defaultview?view=netcore-3.1)

Sample code:

```
    Dim connection As New SqlConnection(" server info")
    Dim sda As New SqlDataAdapter("select * from table", connection)
    Dim dt As New DataTable
    sda.Fill(dt)
    dt.DefaultView.RowFilter = "type = 'x'"
    DataGridView1.DataSource = dt
```